# Are few of the server variables been added and few have been removed in PHP 7?

Tags: php, superglobals, server-variables

I am learning **PHP** from **w3schools' PHP** tutorial. I'm using **PHP 7.0.13**

While learning I come across the concept of **Global Variables - Superglobals**.

[This is the page from where I'm learning **Global Variables - Superglobals**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp)

**Note : Please go to the above link to check the listing of server variables.**

On this page I tried with all the server variables but I receive **Notice** as **Undefined index** for following few server variables :

1. `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET']`
2. `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`
3. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`
4. `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']`

For each of the above variables I tried following code. For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <pre>
    <?php
      echo $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'];//like this I tried for other three server variables also
    ?>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apart from this I also observed few new server variables are there in the array `$_SERVRER` when I tried to execute the code `print_r($_SERVER);`

So, my question is are few of the old server variables present in PHP5 have been removed in PHP7 and few others have been newly added?

I also tried to check in **PHP Documentation** but there also I couldn't get any idea about this.

So, please someone please clarify my doubts.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Comment: Which values exist almost entirely depends on the *web server*, which is passing them to PHP (yes, that's why they're in the `$_SERVER` superglobal). So… what web server are you running this on?

Comment: @deceze : I'm using Apache/2.4.23 (Win32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content of `$_SERVER` is mainly created by web server, as [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
>   and script locations. **The entries in this array are created by the web
>   server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any
>   of these**; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.
>   That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the
>   » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

so PHP got very little to do here.